# Пишу бэкенд для сайта на flask, но почему-то пропадает session

Tags: python, flask

Есть некий код, в котором я login-ю пользователя, и добавляю его в сессию:

```py
session['username'] = user[1]
```

но почему то потом, когда проверяю какая же инфа сохранилась в session

```py
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
    response_object = {'status': 'success'}
    response_object['message'] = session.get('username')


    return jsonify(response_object)
```

но на страницу flask-а выводиться
**{"message":null,"status":"success"}**
Помогите, в чем ошибка?

P.S.

```py
user = cursor.fetchone() #инфа из бд
```

Comment: Начать стоит с двух логичных вопросов: 1) Сохранилась ли сессионная кука в браузере вообще? 2) Что такое `user[1]`?

Comment: Как первое проверить я не знаю, а вот второе user = cursor.fetchone(), крч нужный пользователе из бд @andreymal